# Logistic Regression CV multiple scoring metrics

Tags: python, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I am creating a model on classification problem using Logistic Regression.

Data - 5000*100

As the data is small, I really wanted to utilize the Logistic Regression CV as it helps in not breaking the data into train and test separately and in turn increase the training set

I wanted to see the CV score of Precision, Recall and F1-score for all the 5 folds and fit the model on Accuracy

The code is giving the below error -
dict object is not callable

Code used -

```
C=[np.power(10.0,0)]
scorers = {
                'precision_score': make_scorer(precision_score),
                'recall_score': make_scorer(recall_score),
                'accuracy_score': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
                'AUC': 'roc_auc',
                'Accuracy' : 'accuracy'
                } 
clf3 = LogisticRegressionCV(penalty="l1", max_iter=100, solver='liblinear', n_jobs=30, cv=5, Cs=C, scoring=scorers, refit='accuracy')
clf3.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

What am I doing wrong here, Also, does LogisticregressionCV supports multiple metrics for scoring?

Really appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You've identified the problem; LogisticregressionCV does not support multiple metrics for `scoring`. You need to pass a function rather than a dictionary.